# Resources and getString() returns wrong translation of text

Tags: android, kotlin, resources, getstring

Inside my Fragment I fetch a string which returns French translation but I want it to return **English** translation. What I noticed so far:

```
binding.textView = resources.getString(R.string.displayText) // returns French translation
binding.textView = getString(R.string.displayText) // returns English text
```

The issue seems to be when I use `resources`. I don't understand how and why this happens, both examples will call `public String getString(int resId)` inside Resources.

How can one return French text and the other one return English when both call the same getString() function?

I've tried using StringResources but that class is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: Where are you getting the instance 'resources' from?

Comment: It's defined inside the ViewModel's constructor as ```val resources: Resources```, and I use koin dependency injection inside a Module class: ```resources = get<Context>().resources```

Answer (score 0):

Every `Resources` has independent `Configuration`, and the `Configuration`'s local determines the `Resources`'s language.
You can print your `resources.getConfiguration().getLocales()` to check its local.
Maybe its Configuration was modified or the resources belongs to another context.

The default implemention of `getString()` is `getResources().getString()`, it use the default context's Resources.

Comment: ```resources.configuration.locales``` returns [en_GB], so it's weird that I still get German translation by using ```resources.getString()```.

Comment: French* translation